# Subtracting columns in a Vlookup

Tags: excel

I have a Excel spreadsheet that has two tabs, I have data on the DATA tab and the results of the data on the RESULTS tab. On the RESULTS tab I need to create a vlookup that will look for data on the DATA tab and subtract Column A from Column B. Is this possible with vlookup?

I have a before and after with the same clientID but data being copied/pasted will change.

```
Before 
A        B      C
1021    102    125.00
1022    102    150.00
1023    105    100.00

After
A       B        C
1021   102   125.00
1022   102   
1023   105   100.00
```

So each day I take the AFTER number and paste them over the before number, and get my new AFTER numbers from another tab.But if the pasted AFTER number does not have data for that specific account (in this case 1022), and the new AFTER number I get from another tab does not have data for 1022, my comparision will be off an account and will not notify me that this account is missing. I'm sorry, i know that is probably confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't actually get why you need to use VLOOKUP to substract two columns...

In the results tab, you could just type

```
=IF(AND(DATA!B1<>"",DATA!A1<>""),DATA!B1-DATA!A1,"")
```

And copy the formula down the whole column.

The IF condition checks if both DATA!B1 and DATA!A1 are not empty, in which case it means they both have data and it will substract it. If one of the two columns is empty, it won't do anything, which is what you want.

If I didn't understand your question correctly, feel free to comment and clarify and I will propose something else.

**Edit for VLOOKUP solution:**  I'm assuming that the client IDs are in column A in both tabs and you have to substract B from C in the same row as the ID in the DATA tab.

In RESULTS, use the following formula (put this one in row number 1 and copy it down):

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,DATA!A:C,3,FALSE)-VLOOKUP(A1,DATA!A:C,2,FALSE)
```

This will return 0 if both fields are empty, C if only B is empty and -B if only C is empty.

I can modify this if you need a different behavior depending on which columns are empty.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I have a list of accounts on my RESULTS tab, is there a way to permanently keep this list of accounts even if on the DATA tab the account has no data? If that doesnt make sense please let me know and i will try to give a better explanation

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep a permanent list of accounts such as the Client ID and Name or do you mean you want to keep the actual results you calculated (e.g.: The result of B1-A1 is 3 and you want to permanently keep the 3 even after the data is deleted)?

Comment: permanent list of accts such as the CLient ID. BC I am copy/pasting data onto the DATA tab and sometimes a row will be blank which will make one of my columns i am comparing off.

Comment: Can you post an example of how your file is formatted so I can write the formulas for you? VLOOKUP might be a better option if you do have a Client ID in both tables, but I'd need to know what kind of data is contained in each row, that would help me help you better.

Comment: What you could do is copy/paste your data onto the DATA tab with the first column being your client ID (ex: A1 is Client ID and A2 and A3 are the data to be substracted). Then, in the RESULTS tab, you could have all of your client IDs in the first column as well and use a VLOOKUP to find the corresponding data from DATA. That way, even with blank cells, everything is going to keep working. I'll edit my answer to show you how to use VLOOKUP in this case without breaking accounts that don't have data to parse

Comment: it does help but only column C is being subtracted from each other, Column b is just a reference code.

Comment: In Vlookup, you can just pass entire columns, like B:D, that way if you add rows, your formula will never be off.

Comment: This is what I used in my example. As for your issue, just change the letters to the letters representing the columns you have the data to substract in. Currently, it is column C minus column B, change those letters to what you see fit

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with Vloopup.

```
=VLOOKUP(ResultsRefID,DATAarray,col1,FALSE)-VLOOKUP(ResultsRefID,DATAarray,col2,FALSE)
```

you could use that formula where ResultsRefID is the unique row identifier you are trying to get data for, DATAarray is all of the data in the DATA worksheet, and col1/col2 are the columns of data you want to have subtracted.

You can get the same results a little easier (I think) with an IF statement as an array.

```
=IF(ResultsRefID=DATAarrayUniqueIDrow1:DATAarrayUniqueIDrow1lastRow,col1FirstRow:col1LastRow-col2Firstrow:col2LastRow,"match not found.")
```

The IF statement has to be entered as an array (ctrl+shift+return)